# Ruby Histogram formatting?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, histogram

I'm in the middle of writing a histogram and have ran into a problem. I'm not quite sure how to get the letters of the alphabet next to what will be the histogram, as in D: 2. At the moment they just print after each other like this:

```
A
B
C
D

0
0
0
2
```

Here's the code I've got so far, any ideas what needs adding/re-arranging as i'm quite stuck! Thanks alot! Without using gems please

```
class String

def frequency
letters = Hash.new(0)
self.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').upcase.delete(','+''+' ').each_char {|c| letters[c] += 1 }
letters = letters.sort_by {|x,y| y }
end

def histogram
myhash = Hash.new(0)
#freq = self.frequency;
self.each_char {|i| myhash[i] += 1}
('a'..'z').each { | c , v | puts myhash[c] } 

end
end
```

Comment: We cannot tell what you expect from looking at what you do not expect. Furthermore, the characters in the picture are too small to read anyway.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you'd make that black box a little smaller.  It's giving me a headache.

Comment: Please do the following: (1) Remove the picture (2) Add sample output as text (3) Take a look at the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) (4) Indent your code correctly.

Comment: all it shows is the letters A-Z with the numbers below of how many times that letter appears in some given text, i'll fix the stuff now ^

Comment: You've got the right idea.  `frequency` looks OK, and you should use it in `histogram` as I see you have previously.  Note that each letter e is to be printed in column j of the `myhash.keys.max - myhash[e]`th row that you print (starting with row zero), where e is the `j`th largest element in the hash.  The down votes would be for the presentation of the question, not the question itself, which is fine.

Comment: Please follow @screenmutt's advice, when though you've accepted an answer (which leaves many of us shaking or heads), as others will read your question in future, and you owe it to them to express it properly.  It is to your benefit as well; the positive impression of a clever answer is often less than the the negative impression of a sloppy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Witout easy-to-copy-paste test code, I cannot give a verified answer in short time. Maybe you can provide more code with a testcase. As others pointed out this will **not** print a histogram, but a table with the letters from "small a" to "small z" and how often they occur in the string.

Few pointers

- rename `histogram` in `print_character_count`
- iterate over a-z like this ('a'..'z').each { | c | puts "#{c} #{myhash[c]}" }

Will lead to following output:

```
"notananswer".print_character_count
a 2
b 0
c 0
d 0
e 1
...
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help felix! got it sorted now was just missing that #{c} before myhash :D thanks again :)

Comment: Felix, that's not a [histogram](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).

Comment: @CarySwoveland his solution helped me to fix what was wrong with mine which is now a working histogram :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: you are right - thanks for pointing out! I edited my answer to make that clear. Anyway the problem was not about the histogram but about the formatting.